# Laravel Query Builder not working, Show error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have the following query used in Laravel Framework

```
$student_attendance_search_result = DB::table('tbl_student_attendance')
        ->join('tbl_student_admission', 'tbl_student_attendance.student_id', '=', 'tbl_student_admission.student_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('tbl_student_attendance.*,tbl_student_admission.student_id,tbl_student_admission.student_full_name_english,tbl_student_admission.class,tbl_student_admission.section,tbl_student_admission.roll_no, count(case when attendance_status ="Absent"  then 1 end) as total_absent,count(case when attendance_status ="Present" then 1 end) as total_present,count(case when attendance_status ="Leave" then 1 end) as total_leave,count(distinct date) as total_class'))
        ->where('tbl_student_attendance.academic_year', $academic_year)
        ->where('tbl_student_admission.class', $classs)
        ->where('tbl_student_admission.section', $section)
        ->where('tbl_student_attendance.month', $month)
        ->groupBy('tbl_student_admission.student_id')
        ->get();
```

It is throwing the following exception when i am trying to run it

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'db_smsfinal1user.tbl_student_attendance.student_attendance_id' isn't
>   in GROUP BY (SQL: select `tbl_student_attendance`.*,
>   `tbl_student_admission`.`student_id`,
>   `tbl_student_admission`.`student_full_name_english`,
>   `tbl_student_admission`.`class`, `tbl_student_admission`.`section`,
>   `tbl_student_admission`.`roll_no`, count(case when attendance_status
>   ="Absent" then 1 end) as total_absent,count(case when attendance_status ="Present" then 1 end) as total_present,count(case
>   when attendance_status ="Leave" then 1 end) as
>   total_leave,count(distinct date) as total_class from
>   `tbl_student_attendance` inner join `tbl_student_admission` on
>   `tbl_student_attendance`.`student_id` =
>   `tbl_student_admission`.`student_id` where
>   `tbl_student_attendance`.`academic_year` = 2018 and
>   `tbl_student_admission`.`class` = 2 and
>   `tbl_student_admission`.`section` = None and
>   `tbl_student_attendance`.`month` = September group by
>   `tbl_student_admission`.`student_id`)

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: This syntax is standard for SQL, and I suppose no conversion is needed, doesn't it?

Comment: In laravel it's not working

Answer (score 0):

use DB::raw as select arguments

`DB::select(
  DB::raw('student_id,count(case when attendance_status ='Absent'  then 1 end) as absent_count,count(case when attendance_status ='Present' then 1 end) as present_count,count(case when attendance_status ='Leave' then 1 end) as leave_count,count(distinct date) as Tot_count')
)->from(..)->groupBy(...);`